# Member predicate

Tags: prolog, unification

When you call `member(Item, List)` with an uninstanciated list, Prolog unifies and returns a list containing item. I want a rule that returns `true`/`false` and does not try to unify. Is there such a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a guard, like

```
is_member(E, L) :- nonvar(L), memberchk(E, L).
```

[`memberchk/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2) it's a deterministic version of member/2, to be used to find if the list contains at least 1 occurrence of element. Cannot act as a *generator*, but it's more efficient. The guard is required anyway.

Comment: According to OP, `is_member(E, L)` should be true, but your definition fails.

Comment: @false: well, you must read something *very* different than me in OP question.

Comment: I read the OP's questions as wanting a predicate that would return false if given an instantiated `E` and uninstantiated `L`, it would fail rather than return a list in `L` that contained `E`. However, it appears they accepted this answer, so perhaps they didn't specify their question precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: Use `\+ \+ member(Item, List)`.

Please note that such tests often do not make a lot of sense when your programs represent logical relations.

You stated that `member(Item, List)` "returns a list". Well, that is not entirely true. `List` is unified with **partial lists**, that is `List = [Item|_Rest] ; List = [_,Item|_Rest] ; ...` with `_Rest` being an uninstantiated variable. That is, the goal `member(Item, List)` does not guarantee that (upon success) `List` is a list. Here is a counterexample: `member(Item, List), List = [_|nonlist]`

Comment: Thanks! What do the \+'s mean?

Comment: @saadtaame: `(\+)/1` - not provable